# why does itext automatic rotate pdf

Tags: itext, autorotate

When I append an one page PDF to a large PDF itext always rotates 180 degree then appends. Did someone else encounter same issue? I used both `iText-5.0.6.jar` and `itextpdf-5.4.0.jar`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a low quality question. Please provide more information, your set up at least.

Comment: I can assure you that doesn't happen when i append. Thus, there most likely something is wrong with your append-code. As you didn't show it, though, we cannot pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason: when the PDf file being generated through a scan machine there are some setting and the property of rotation was set to 180. When manipulating the PDF file later it automatically turns down. It can be checked by method PdfImportedPage.getRotation().